# onbeforeunload change the UI of dialog box or use custom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page where if user click anywhere outside form or try to close the tab a dialog box/popup should come like your changes will be discard or do you want to move.

I can do this from window.onbeforeunload event but the problem is that i need to use a customized pretty dialog box instead of default one if any alternate approach is there.

If we use any modal dialog box but i don't know which event to call on that dialog also tried window.onload but it not fulfill my problem as i need to ask the viewer before moving to other page.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: There is no problem but the window.onbeforeunload event i think you can't change the ui design i need to make it pretty.